# Electric range not working properly

Tags: range

The clock and the oven light work but not the oven or burners.  I read it may be the thermal fuse but my stove was old so I replaced it and I am having the same problem.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Might you have a problem with your power? (Where in the world are you?)

Comment: Does your stove have a separate plug for 120V (clock, lights) and 240V (burners, oven)?  If so, check the separate breakers.

Answer (score 2):

The oven and the burners are probably 240 V and the clock and light 120 V. This suggests you have lost one leg. It may be the breaker or it may be in the range. Get a voltage tester and first check at the plug and the range. If you have no 240V at the plug or cable then check the voltage at the double pole breaker outputs. If it was before the breaker, then you would have other circuits unpowered and you don't report that.

If the range has a plug, then it is easy to check the voltages at the plug. Then check the voltages at the connection block on the back of the range.

Comment: This is the path I would take the problem was narrowed down to the supply with both units not functioning imo.+

Comment: I don't think piercing the insulation on the wires is a good idea. Might be okay when testing 12 VDC milliampere circuits, not so good for 120/240 VAC 50 ampere circuits. Just my opinion.

Comment: I removed the suggestion to pierce the insulation to test voltage.